# Service worker trying to install but never runs Angular in Chrome browser

Tags: angular, google-chrome, service-worker

I need to send web push notifications to the users but, because the service worker does not run sending web push notifications fails. Please help me

```
export function getRequest(): any {
      return { headers: { cookie: document.cookie } };
    }
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'halkaarzui' }),
        AppRoutes,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        TransferHttpCacheModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule,
        CoreModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
          enabled: environment.production,
          // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
          // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
        }),
        CalculateModule
      ],
      providers: [
        DatePipe,
        NgbActiveModal,
        {
          // The server provides these in main.server
          provide: REQUEST,
          useFactory: getRequest,
        },
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: LOCALE_ID},],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

[image]